# Wpf's ComboBox not firing SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a scenario where combobox can have same string values. for exa combo box can have following values in drop down:
 "Test",
 "Test1",
 "Test1",
 "Test1",
 "Test2",

On the basis of selected index I am filling another combobox. My Xaml Looks like:

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboList, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ComboIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/ >
</Grid>
```

ViewModel looks like:

```
class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList<string> _comboList = new List<string>
                                      {
                                          "Test",
                                          "Test1",
                                          "Test1",
                                          "Test1",
                                          "Test2",
                                      };       

    public IList<string> ComboList
    {
        get { return _comboList; }
    }


    private int _comboIndex;

    public int ComboIndex
    {
        get { return _comboIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _comboIndex)
            {
                return;
            }

            _comboIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ComboIndex");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Problem I am facing is that SelectedIndex does not get fired incase I am suffling between same string value (like changing value from "Test1" ,present at index 1, to "Test1", present at index 2.

Comment: *Problem I am facing is that SelectedIndex does not get fired incase I am suffling between same string value*.  This statement doesn't make sense.  You're binding to the index, which will always be different.

Comment: @blindmeis: I am using selected index because on the basis of selectedindex I need to fill another combobox. Anyhow even SelectedItem or selectedvalue does not get fired in descibed scenario.

Comment: Can you post your related view model code?

Comment: @ dbaseman: YES. Fully agree with you. But irony is that it does not get fired. It is either a bug in Wpf or Wpf compare string value or something before firing it.

Comment: @wdavo: Updated with viewmodel code

Comment: Works fine for me.  Can you show your view model?

Comment: @Phil: updated the description with viewmodel. All you have to add a breakpoint in ComboIndex's set. and after running it, change the value from "Test1" to another "Test1".

Comment: Works fine for me using your view model and xaml. If this is part of something larger you might need to post some more related code.

Comment: @wdavo: strange that it works for you. All I am doing is: 1) Run it 2)Select "Test" 3) Select "Test1" 4) Select "Test1" at index3................                                                         For 4th point i dont get control in set of ComboIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to a `List<string>`, encapsulate the strings, e.g.

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string v){ Value = v; }
    public string Value{get; private set;}
}
```

and bind to a `List<Item>`.

Then amend your Xaml to specify the DisplayMemberPath

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboList, Mode=OneWay}"  
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ComboIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/ >
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

when i need such relations i create the relations in my viewmodel and simply bind to this collection

```
 public class MyItem
 {
    public string Name {get; set;}//your Test, Test1, Test1 ...
    public List<string> Childs {get; set;} // the childs depending on the the Name
 }
```

in your viewmodel you can now create your List of MyItem and fill it like you need.

```
 public List<MyItem> MyItemList {get;set;}
```

in xaml you can now simply create your related comboboxes.

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ComboIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/ >

 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboIndex.Childs}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedPropForChild, Mode=TwoWay}"/ >
```

so you dont have to care of any index cause you already build your relations.